# Brownian motion on a manifold

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, manifolds, brownian-motion

If I have a manifold $M$ and a chart $\left(x,U\right)$, is it possible to simulate Brownian motion on that manifold by solving an SDE in the chart representation $x\left(U\right)$ and then use the chart map $x$ to map the solution onto the manifold? Of course this would only be valid up to the time the process leaves $x\left(U\right)$.